# Multiple FORM select statements

Tags: html

I think I may have a unique issue, or at least I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere on the internet.  I have a FORM that when a selection is made on a select option above it choose the next select option to show.  So basically I have multiple select options with the same name but only one group of select options shows up depending on what I selected on the choice before it.  The problem is that when I make a selection to a select option in the first group, the result (value) always shows up as the first option in the last select statement with the same name.  Here is a snippet:

```
<label for="mainIssue" id="mainIssueLabel" class="labelTitle" style="display:none;">Main Issue:</label>

                <select name="mainIssue" id="warrantyFiltrationType" style="display:none;">
                        <option value="Type Filtration">Select One</option>
                        <option value="CP2000">CP2000</option>
                        <option value="RX">RX</option>
                        <option value="SFS">SFS</option>
                        <option value="SFX">SFX</option>
                        <option value="RP">RP</option>
                        <option value="Sand">SAND</option>
                </select>

                <select name="mainIssue" id="warrantyPumpType" style="display:none;">
                        <option value="Type Pump">Select One</option>
                        <option value="F350C">F350C</option>
                        <option value="F400C">F400C</option>
                        <option value="F600C-9">F600C GFCI 9</option>
                        <option value="F600C-18">F600C GFCI 18</option>
                        <option value="F700800C">F700C/800C</option>
                        <option value="F1000C">F1000C</option>
                        <option value="F1500C">F1500C</option>
                        <option value="F2000C">F2000C</option>
                        <option value="X600">X600</option>                  
                        <option value="X1000">X1000</option>
                        <option value="X1500">X1500</option>                        
                        <option value="CP2000C">CP2000C</option>
                </select>
```

Say the select that comes up is the filtration select options.  No matter which option I choose in the filtration selection, the value always shows up as value "Type Pump", or the first option in the last selection with the same name.

It appears that even though the correct selection options are showing, only the last selection option group is being read.

Any clues?

Comment: _`Any clues?`_ Yes, don't give the selects all the same name.

Comment: "Being read" by what?  If you're posting a form with multiple elements of the same name then the last one will take priority.  This is why names should be unique in forms.

Comment: but I want to store the values in the same database field.  I don't want to have to create a column for every selection.

Comment: @John: What does that have to do with the `name` attribute on form elements?  Either give your elements unique names or use a single `select` populated with different `option`s.

Comment: Sounds like there is no other choice.  I guess I will have to create multiple columns in the database, some will just remain as null if they don't apply.  Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Hi David.  I was trying to avoid having 50 options in a single select statement.  I am using java script to choose only the options that apply to a specific topic...ie, filtration shows only the options under the select statement for filtration, but since the data in all the select statements will be inserted into the same column in the database, I wanted to avoid having multiple select names that would in turn need multiple columns in the database.

Comment: why are using name when you have id in the select tags ?

Comment: You can always combine the different select values programmatically before inserting anything into your database.

Comment: @John: `"I guess I will have to create multiple columns in the database"` - Well, you can do that if you really want to.  But there's no rule that says you *have to*.  Having a database table with many almost-always-null columns seems like a pretty poor design choice.  I can't stress enough the fact that this is client side code and has *nothing* to do with a database.

Comment: @DinoMyte: name attributes are how the server gets the input fields data (name => value), where as the id of an input is generally used for styling or client side scripting purposes. It is good practice to put an id and name on all input fields, even if you don't plan on using them right away, as in the future you may want to validate data via javascript on specific fields or adjust styles of specific input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @David, if your intention is to post the data and you want all select fields with the same name to post the data to the server, then you need to use unique names...

OR...

In the name attribute, you need to append a [] to the end of the name that is the same across multiple selects / inputs.

An example of this which uses your code is as follows

```
<select name="mainIssue[]" id="warrantyPumpType" style="display:none;">
```

Note that this will post to the server where mainIssue is an array of each of the datasets.

Note that another small change may be what your looking for..

```
<select name="mainIssue['warrantyFiltrationType']" id="warrantyFiltrationType" style="display:none;">
```

and

```
<select name="mainIssue['warrantyPumpType']" id="warrantyPumpType" style="display:none;">
```

Note that all I did here was throw your id's into the square brackets to "name those keys". When this is posted to the server, your $_POST data (assuming your using php to capture the post), will be a multi-array where $_POST['mainIssue'] is an array with the key => values your expecting.

**-EDIT-**

To take this further, you would probably want your "Select One" option's value to be null or empty...

...And on the server, you would simply check for the mainIssue['specificKey'] which has a value that is not empty. With this method, you can then take the single selected value (from which ever select that it was selected in) and store it into the single DB field you need it in.

**-EDIT-**

An example in php side would be to loop over the array that came in, and simply check.

```
$mainIssue = ''; // This is what ever you want to default to before checking for the value of mainIssue
foreach($_POST['mainIssue'] as $key => $value) {
    if($value != '') { // If the value is empty, then they did not select an item in that specific select field
        $mainIssue = $value; // If the value was selected, then there would be a non-empty value somewhere in the multi-dimension array of mainIssue, and here is where we capture it
    }
}
// So at this point of the code $mainIssue variable has a value of what ever was selected, else what ever the default was set before the loop above
```

You would want to make sure your "Select One" option's value attribute is empty for this to work (for all your selects which have the same name)

```
            <select name="mainIssue[]" id="warrantyFiltrationType" style="display:none;">
                    <option value="">Select One</option>
                    <option value="CP2000">CP2000</option>
                    <option value="RX">RX</option>
                    <option value="SFS">SFS</option>
                    <option value="SFX">SFX</option>
                    <option value="RP">RP</option>
                    <option value="Sand">SAND</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Hi NinjaKC.  I am using PHP.  I am POSTing the data to a page that will display the values selected.  I am also using a function to test the data (trim, stripslashes, etc).  I am not figuring out how I can extract just the value from the POST value that is sent to the server so I can then move the value to the function.  Even when I use the mainIssue['warrantyPumpType'], the POST data is being seen as an array, is there a way to see what that array has within it and to extract the value and save it under a variable name?

Comment: It worked.  I added the following in my sever side and got the value I needed submitted to the database.  All I need to do now is follow suite on the remain "same named" select fields.  THANK YOU.

Comment: if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  
  $date           = $_POST["date"];
  $callType       = $_POST["callType"];
  $purchaseYear   = $_POST["purchaseYear"];
  $purchasePlace  = $_POST["purchasePlace"];
  $itemType       = $_POST["itemType"];
  $callReason     = $_POST["callReason"];
   foreach($_POST['mainIssue'] as $key => $value) {
    if($value != '') {
     $mainIssue =$value;
    } 
   }
  $secondaryIssue = $_POST["secondaryIssue"];
  $result         = $_POST["result"];

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple form elements with the same `name`:

```
<select name="mainIssue"
...
<select name="mainIssue"
```

When posting a form to the server, the `name` of any given element is the "key" in its "key/value pair".  Thus, it must be unique in that form post.  As the browser builds the form post, any element it finds with the same name as a previous element is going to overwrite that one in the form post.  (This behavior may be undefined and browser-specific.)

Basically, give your form input elements unique names.  You can do this by either:

- Having multiple `select` elements with unique `name`s.
- Having a single `select` element which you dynamically re-populate with `option`s based on user selection.

Comment: Gentlemen.  Thank you very much for your input.  This gives me a starting place to research my solution.  I have tried (to a point) using the array option that NinjaKC suggested but I could not figure out how to extract the actual option that was selected from that array in PHP.  I also like Davids suggestion of dynamically populating a single select statement, I think I could come up with a javascript solution for that, sounds like a lot of typing though.